# How to call a Toast when option button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Here by option button I meant a hard button in most android devices its image is

[image]

I can do it when back button is pressed by this way:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Back button is pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think overriding onOptionsItemSelected() method should do the trick,,,

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: You are referring to is menu button but the mentioned gets called on back button.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs -->  I tried onOptionsItemSelected() but Toast is not appearing.

Comment: how do You have done it? Show some code.....or follow Rhoit5K2´s example, that als works...

Comment: This is a story, what is your question.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt ,read the title of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to option button but the code you have written gets called on back button. You should do this instead

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Back button is pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; //prevent this event from being propagated further
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```